# Configurar de forma correcta las rutas en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo las rutas configuras en mi archivo crud.js de la siguiente forma:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'vistas/estudiantes.html',
    controller: 'ListarEstudiantesController'
}).when('/estudiantes',{
    templateUrl: 'vistas/estudiantes.html',
    controller: 'ListarEstudiantesController'
}).when('/estudiantes/nuevo',{
    templateUrl: 'vistas/form.estudiante.html',
    controller: 'CrearEstudianteController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}).when('/estudiantes/:id/edit',{
    templateUrl: 'vistas/form.estudiante.html',
    controller: 'EditarEstudianteController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}).otherwise({redirecTo: 'vistas/estudiantes.html'});
```

});

Y en mi archivo estudiantes.html tengo el siguiente boton:

```
<a href="#/estudiantes/nuevo" class="btn btn-primary">Crear estudiante</a>
```

Pero al dar click al boton no va a la ruta, pero si la escribo en la barrade direcciones del navegador si funciona.

Comment: supongo que es angular 1.x por favor observa la ayuda https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: cuando usas angular y hagas algo como lo que tienes en la navegacion te va a dar error por que toma la primera ruta como principal (/estudiantes) y si tratas de hacer /estudiantes/nuevo vas a tener error te recomiendo separarlo o hagas algo como estudiante_nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, ya probaste colocando el link de esta manera?

`<a href="#!/estudiantes/nuevo" class="btn btn-primary">Crear estudiante</a>`